# Can WebRTC be used for backend data transmission for IOT?

Tags: webrtc

We are building a data transmission backend from IOT device to our backend system built in backend and hosted on cloud. Found this [W3 working draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc-nv-use-cases/#iot*) that mentions the use case.

Does WebRTC have any advantage over traditional API data push from IOT device?

Most of use cases covered in explanations on internet are for peer to peer communication for which Webrtc is perfect fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a lot of developers using WebRTC for their IoT projects! Recently it has been our biggest group of contributors to Pion.

The nice thing about using DataChannels (vs other APIs)

- Support in the browser (no need for a backend to bridge protocols)
- You have different delivery options (Out-of-order or lossy for better performance)
- Mandatory security. WebRTC it always over DTLS, many other protocols is optional
- Available in lots of languages (C, C++, Python, Java, Go...) these aren't just FFI implementations, but first-class and pleasant to use.